# Como fazer select pegando o registro que tem o valor máximo de um campo?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou fazendo um select que está buscando registros que cumprem algumas condições e depois deveria pegar dentre eles apenas o registro que tem o valor máximo de um determinado campo.

Está assim:

```
SELECT 
    VP.VAL_PREVISTO
FROM 
    TB_META M 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_SUPER_FUNCAO_META SFM ON 
    M.COD_META = SFM.COD_META 
    AND SFM.COD_FUNCAO = (SELECT F.COD_SUPER_FUNCAO U FROM TB_USUARIO U INNER JOIN TB_FUNCAO F ON U.COD_FUNCAO = F.COD_FUNCAO WHERE U.COD_USUARIO = 5)
INNER JOIN
    TB_VALOR_PREVISTO VP ON
    M.COD_META = VP.COD_META
INNER JOIN
    TB_CG_META_PERIODO CGMP ON
    VP.COD_VALOR_PREVISTO = CGMP.COD_VALOR_PREVISTO       
WHERE
    SFM.IND_EXIBIR_MC_CG = 1 AND M.COD_META = 44 AND CGMP.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 4
```

Nessa query eu estou buscando o período: `CGMP.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 4` porém eu não quero especificar o período, pois o período máximo pode ser maior que isso. Queria que a query pegasse o registro com valor máximo de periodo, mas só depois de cumprir os outros "where".

Answer (score 2):

Uma das soluções é fazeres uma subquery para ir buscar o `MAX` desse elemento:

```
SELECT 
    VP.VAL_PREVISTO
FROM 
    TB_META M 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_SUPER_FUNCAO_META SFM ON 
    M.COD_META = SFM.COD_META 
    AND SFM.COD_FUNCAO = (SELECT F.COD_SUPER_FUNCAO U FROM TB_USUARIO U INNER JOIN TB_FUNCAO F ON U.COD_FUNCAO = F.COD_FUNCAO WHERE U.COD_USUARIO = 5)
INNER JOIN
    TB_VALOR_PREVISTO VP ON
    M.COD_META = VP.COD_META
INNER JOIN
    TB_CG_META_PERIODO CGMP ON
    VP.COD_VALOR_PREVISTO = CGMP.COD_VALOR_PREVISTO       
WHERE
    SFM.IND_EXIBIR_MC_CG = 1 AND M.COD_META = 44 
    AND CGMP.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = (
        SELECT MAX(C.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO)
        FROM TB_CG_META_PERIODO C
    )
```

Comment: Mas e se "SELECT MAX(C.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO) 
        FROM TB_CG_META_PERIODO C" for diferente dos resultados obtidos nas minhas primeiras condições where? Ficarei sem resultados, certo?

Comment: Que condições estás a falar @JoaoPaulo? As do `SFM.IND_EXIBIR_MC_CG = 1 AND M.COD_META = 44` ou as do  JOIN?

Comment: Busquei onde SFM.IND_EXIBIR_MC_CG = 1 AND M.COD_META = 44. Com essas condições obtenho resultados onde o período máximo é 3, mas o período máximo da tabela é 6 por exemplo. Se eu adicionar a condição que você disse eu encontrarei o 6 e não o 3 que eu quero.

Comment: Terei que usar uma condição praticamente igual ao meu select original? Estava vendo se tinha alguma alternativa mais simples.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, já entendi. Para fazeres isso na subquery vais ter mesmo de colocar as condições para ir buscar o teu máximo. Se dizes que vai ser com base no `SFM.IND_EXIBIR_MC_CG` e `M.COD_META`, então precisam de lá estar. No entanto não consegui perceber onde é que esses dados vão influenciar num suposto máximo do `CGMP.NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO`. Precisa de haver uma relação entre ambas as tabelas